Quarto markdowns no longer honor yaml headers
I have a few qmd files that I'm updating with new base data. I have NOT changed any of the code in these files, just the data being fed into them. For whatever reason yesterday the yaml headers have stopped working. It will display the title and author correctly but all other entries do nothing. All I really need is the execute: echo: false tag to work and I'll be happy. But rendering today the date: today entry doesn't work and all of the echo and warning messages appear when they shouldn't.
I just upgraded Rstudio and no change. Does anyone have any idea what's going on?
Example.qmd
---
title: "This title displays correctly"
author: "So does the author"
date: today <--THIS DOES NOT
format:
  html:
    code-fold: true
    code-background: false
execute: 
  warning: false
  echo: false
rendering:
  embed-resources: true
  self-contained-math: true
---



Seems like an issue for the Quarto GitHub if you can include a minimal example and your session info, especially the Quarto version. As a workaround, if all your code blocks are R, you could add a code block at the beginning setting  the knitr options, e.g. knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE). Also it sounds like you're running the Quarto that is bundled with RStudio, so you could try installing Quarto separately and see if that resolves it.

As a workaround you could use:
date: "\r Sys.Date()`"`

Thanks SamR, I did try individual install of Quarto with no luck. I can use knitr options as a workaround but would still like to understand why the change occurred. I'll reach out to Quarto on GitHub and see if they have any answers.
